# Representing FOL in english language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have the following FOL formula: `∀e(S(e)) → ∃d(P(d))`

And the vocabulary:
`variables: e:'exam', d:'day'
functions: S:'successful', P:'party'`

I initially translated that formula into:
`For every successful exam, there will be a day of party`

While apparently the correct translation would be something of the sort of:
`You party at least one day after all exams were successful.`

Why does the correct one say that we only party after ALL exams were successful?

Does `∀e(S(e))` mean: "For all exams, they will all be successful"? 
And `∃d(P(d))` mean: "there exists at least one day where we party"?

And doesn't the implication translte to "if a then b" ?

I think I can somehow see the logic of the correct translation, but there's something about the implication that makes me unsure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful here. This formula:

```
∀e(S(e)) → ∃d(P(d))
```

Really only has one precise sense, the one you acknowledge as apparently correct:

> If all exams are successful, then there will be a party.

Your translation is wrong for a subtle but significant reason. Your translation:

> For every successful exam, there will be a day of party

Corresponds to this formula:

```
∀e.∃d(S(e) → P(d))
```

These formulae are not logically equivalent, that is, the following is not a tautology:

```
(∀e(S(e)) → ∃d(P(d))) <=> (∀e.∃d(S(e) → P(d)))
```

To see this, consider what happens when you pass ten exams and fail one exam. The original formula is vacuously true regardless of whether any party is had, since `∀e(S(e))` is not satisfied. However, your statement is only true if you have at least one party, since you did pass at least one exam.

Comment: Thank you for that in-depth answer; However, I do understand the subtle difference, but NOT what _represents_ it in the formula itself. Why does that initial formula mean that there is _**only**_ a party if we pass _all_ exams? I must be missing some basic understanding of the quantifiers or the implication I think?

Comment: @user452306 The original formula does *not* mean there is only a party if all exams are passed. You could still have a party if you failed all the exams and the first formula would remain true. What it means is that you wouldn't need to have a party unless all exams were passed. Your translation means there must be a party if any exam is passed; the original says there must be one if you passed everything. The difference comes down to scope: in the first, the "exists" is totally separate from the "forall", whereas in the second one the "exists" is bound up in the "forall"'s scope.

Comment: Oh, so looking at the implication truth table; the S(e) function will only be true if _all_ exams are passed; and in that case there **must** be at least a party for the formula to be correct. But, if 0 to all-1 exams are passed, the party can or cannot (true or false) take place for the formula to be correct? And for the scope, do I understand that correctly, that if the "exists" is bound to the "forall" that means, that anytime _any_ of the exams is passed, then there is at least 1 party?

Comment: @user452306 For the first point, yes. For the second part, I think this is more or less safe to generalize: forall x there exists a y such that f(x, y) does mean that there must exist at least one y provided there are at least some x (consider that if there are no exams, the first formula guarantees a party whereas the second one does not). Fully parenthesizing can help too: this can help you see that `e` never appears free in any subformula of the first formula, but does appear free in the subformula which binds only `d`.